# How to overwrite permissions on discord for a specific user

Tags: discord, discord.js

I need to make it when you run a command like "!overwide " so only the person you specified cans See the channel, not a whole role. here's the code I have so far. I have tried many different ways of writing it.

```
const { Message } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = { name:'afellow', description: "give a specific person", 
execute(message, args, Discord) {
let memberToFind = message.mentions.members.first();
let channels = [
    '810951137287995495',
    '810952727529127946',
]
 
if (!channels) return message.channel.send('N/A')

if (!memberToFind) return message.channel.send('Mention a user!')


if(message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "FellowshipOwner")) {

    message.channel.updateOverwrite(memberToFind, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true, SEND_MESSAGES: true }).catch();

} else {
    message.channel.send('Sorry, You must be a fellowship owner to use this command.')
}

}


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the member object of the member you mentioned, you can simply update their overwrite in the channel by mentioning the object's variable.

P.S: I've added some more code to your current work and fixed some general errors you had.

#### Final Code

```
const { Message } = require("discord.js")
module.exports = { name:'fellow', description: "give a specific person", execute(message, args, Discord) {

    let memberToFind = message.mentions.members.first();
    /*
      if (!memberToFind) return message.reply('Mention a user!')
    */
    
    if(message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "FellowshipOwner")) {

        message.channel.updateOverwrite(memberToFind, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true, SEND_MESSAGES: true });

    } else {
        message.channel.send('Sorry, You must be a fellowship owner to use this command.')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! thought I had to add something else. Since I want this to be in only a couple channels, I did the code below but it does not seem to work. could you help me again? (i edited my post to show you) the code seems to work in all channels and not jus the channels i specifified.